# Configuring System.Runtime.Caching in appSettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, appsettings, memorycache

I'm trying to configure `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache` in an Asp.NET Core 2.1 application running on the full .NET Framework 4.7.

In another non Asp.NET Core application i configure this in the `Web.config`, like this:

```
<system.runtime.caching>
  <memoryCache>
    <namedCaches>
      <add name="default" cacheMemoryLimitMegabytes="0" physicalMemoryLimitPercentage="0" pollingInterval="00:02:00" />
    </namedCaches>
  </memoryCache>
</system.runtime.caching>
```

However, in the Asp.NET Core 2.1 application I only have `appsetting.json`. How does one configure `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache` in Asp.NET Core 2.1?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at [Cache in-memory in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-2.2), as it seems to describe exactly what you need.

**Update**

You should try using the [AddMemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.memorycacheservicecollectionextensions.addmemorycache?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_MemoryCacheServiceCollectionExtensions_AddMemoryCache_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Action_Microsoft_Extensions_Caching_Memory_MemoryCacheOptions__) overload that accepts a lambda/method used to configure the cache (see [MemoryCacheOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.memorycacheoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.1)), it might look something like:

```
services.AddMemoryCache(options => 
{ 
    options.SizeLimit = 1024; // Can be hardcoded or read from a custom configuration value
})
```

**Update 2**

If you want to use the old package with **ASP.Net Core** you won't be able to use `appSettings.json` to configure it, as **.Net Core**'s uses a different configuration stack.

But, just dropping a `web.config` file in addition to the `appsetings.json` file might work. If it doesn't you'll need to do some heavy customizations to somehow load the old configuration stack with values from the new one before the caching mechanism is loaded, a far from trivial task.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The part of the application which uses System.Runtime.Caching is a module shared with other non-core applications in our suite, so I can't easily rewrite it to something Core-specific.

Comment: System.Runtime.Caching isn't core specific, the only core specific thing you'll need, should be in your Startup class, which is core specific anyway.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I misunderstand. That link descibes using an alternative to System.Runtime.Caching, I however want to still use System.Runtime.Caching because the application in question is not the only application that is dependent on the code. I just want to configure it from appsettings.json.

Comment: That targets `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching`, not `System.Runtime.Caching`?